# Xcode13 | Cant able to add GPX for simulation

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I recently upgraded my Xcode to 13. I can't able to add my GPX file for location simulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can still drag-and-drop a gpx file into the Xcode project.

Next edit the scheme of your project, select Run, and enable "Allow Location Simulation"

[image: enable Allow Location Simulation in your scheme]

Then, when your app is being debugged, you can select your GPX file from the Debug -> Simulate Location menu.

[image: select the GPX file from the Debug Simulate Location menu]